# Thread executing run() method twice

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, progress-bar

I have created a class which extends Thread class, which i am using to show the progress for the music player. Below is the snippet of the code i am sharing,

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    customThread = new CustomThread(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(10)));

 }

 public void playPauseBtn(View v){

   if(isPaused){
    isPaused = false;
    customThread .start();
   else{
    isPaused = true;
   }

 }

static long totalDuration, estimatedMillis;
static boolean isPaused = true;
public class CustomThread extends Thread {

    String name;

    private CustomThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!isPaused) {

            try {

                    estimatedMillis = estimatedMillis + 1000;
                    setProgressData(estimatedMillis);
                    Log.v(TAG,"estimated Millis:"+estimatedMillis );
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The issue here is , when i click on btn to execute playPauseBtn() method, the thread starts running , where the value of estimatedMillis has to be incremented by 1000 which is getting incremented by 2000. In Logcat it is showing the Log statement executed twice, Whereas i am expecting it to increment by 1000 per second.

Please guide me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You `isPaused` is not a `volatile` variable, so JVM does not guarantee that most updated value will be shared between thread. Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors because any write to a volatile variable establishes a `happens-before relationship` with subsequent reads of that same variable

Change `isPaused` to a volatile `static volatile boolean isPaused = true;` will fix your problem.